# How does get text from <Typography /> in jest with react js and typescript

Tags: jestjs, tsx

I am writing jest test case for my project. but I stuck in getting text value in .so,I need how to get text from **Typography**. anyone give solutions.

here i declared my code,

```
let wrapper = shallow(<Typist />).dive();

const pageName = wrapper.find('Typography');

console.log('***pageName***', pageName.debug());
```

here i got this output from pageName

```
***pageName***
<Typography type="h1" className="cr-page__title">
  JobsTitleName
</Typography>
```

i want test this text **JobsTitleName**.

here i used this way,

```
pageName.text()
```

but i got this output, but never i get text **JobsTitleName**.

```
<Typography />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
console.log(wrapper.find('selector').props().children)
```

To get the text from inside

Comment: this also working well,
const pageName = wrapper.find('Typography').dive();
console.log('***pageName***', pageName.text());